# Otherkeywords option causes listings to break

Tags: listings

I'm trying to make a simple language definition for typesetting regular expression. The `otherkeywords` option that the `listings` package provide seems pretty convenient for that. However, it just doesn't seem to work. Here's a MWE of the sort of thing I want to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{regex}{
  otherkeywords={+,*,|,?}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=regex]
[A-Za-z](_?[A-Za-z0-9])*
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\lst@OutputToken ...lst@CheckMerge {\lst@thestyle 
                                                  {\lst@FontAdjust \setbox \...
l.12 [A-Za-z](_?
                [A-Za-z0-9])*
?
```

Clearly, something's going wrong here but I can't imagine what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho it is a bug in lstlistings, there is an internal command for the keywordstyle undefined. Make a bug report.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{regex}{
  otherkeywords={+,*,|,?}
}
\makeatletter \def\lst@gkeywords@sty{\bfseries} %definition for this is missing.
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=regex]
[A-Za-z](_?[A-Za-z0-9])*
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```