htlatex listings emergency stop
I am trying to generate some HTML (using htlatex) from a very simple .tex-file containing some listings. If I do not set my own style, it proceeds as expected and generates the HTML, but when I choose a style, it does an emergency stop. I do not understand why.
My file
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  otherkeywords={<-, ->, ::, \$, [, ], \,, =, |, \{, \}, (, ), -\#, \#-, @},
  keywordstyle=[1]{\color{blue}},
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
f :: Int
f = 5
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

I am trying to color some of my keywords. Can someone shed some light into what I am doing wrong? This is the last bit of the output (the line numbers are different than here because I have some commented out stuff that I removed before writing here)
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.52 f ::
          Int
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.52 f ::
          Int
No pages of output.


Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you get the same error with your given TeX code? If yes, then please show the log file ...

I get an error with your code even with pdflatex. Maybe it is missing some additional configurations?

Your MWE doesn't compile for me even with pdflatex; I get an undefined control sequence error. It seems that the support for otherkeywords in Listings is buggy. Thanfuly, I've found this answer, which enabled me to fix your code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  otherkeywords={<-, ->, ::, \$, [, ], \,, =, |, \{, \}, (, ), -\#, \#-, @},
  % otherkeywords={:},
  keywordstyle=[1]{\color{blue}},
}

% fix for undefined sequence error thanks to Ulrike Fischer
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493913/2891
\makeatletter 
\def\lst@gkeywords@sty{\color{blue}} %definition for this is missing.
\makeatother

\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
f :: Int
f = 5
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

With this fix, you will get no error with pdflatex and you will get blue highlighting of :: and : with both pdflatex and TeX4ht.
There is still a problem with TeX4ht though, which can be fixed with this version of listings.4ht:
% listings.4ht (2024-06-06-15:12), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2001-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-06-06-15:12}

\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{}{%
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
}
\def\lst@makecaption#1#2{\cptA: #1\if :#1:\else\cptB:\fi \cptC: #2\cptD:}

\newif\iflstnest
\append:defII\lst@EnterMode{%
  \ifx \lsthk:EveryLine\:UnDef
     \let\lsthk:EveryLine\lsthk@EveryLine
  \fi
  \ifx \lsthk:EveryLine\lsthk@EveryLine
      \pend:def\lsthk@EveryLine{\c:listings
             \def\dd:listings{\d:listings\let\dd:listings\empty}}%
  \fi
  \append:def\lsthk@EveryPar{\dd:listings}%
  \iflstnest\else
  \a:listings\fi\bgroup
  %\Configure{$}{}{}{}%
  \aftergroup\lst:EnterMode  }
\def\lst:EnterMode{\iflstnest\else\b:listings\fi\egroup}
\NewConfigure{listings}{4}
\let\dd:listings=\empty
\append:defI\lst@Init{\csname a:listings-init\endcsname\global\lstnesttrue}
\pend:def\lst@DeInit{\csname b:listings-init\endcsname\global\lstnestfalse}
\NewConfigure{listings-init}{2}
\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{%
   \Configure{listings}{}{}{}{}%
   \lst@ifmode\else%
   \a:lstinline \bgroup \aftergroup\b:lstinline\aftergroup\egroup%
   \fi%
  }
\NewConfigure{lstinline}{2}
\pend:defI\lst@MakeCaption{%
  \let\lst:addcontentsline\addcontentsline
  \def\addcontentsline{\gHAdvance\TitleCount by 1
                       \lst:addcontentsline}%
}
\append:defI\lst@MakeCaption{%
  \let\addcontentsline\lst:addcontentsline
}
\ConfigureToc{lol} {}{\empty}{}{\newline}
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup%
    \ifdefined\chapter\chapter*{\lstlistlistingname}\else\section*{\lstlistlistingname}\fi%
    \TableOfContents[lol]%
  \egroup}
\def\:tempa{%
   \ifx\lst@OutputBox\@gobble\else \the\everypar \fi
   \global\advance\lst@newlines\m@ne
   \lst@newlinetrue
}%
\HLet\lst@NewLine\:tempa
\def\:tempa#1{
    \begingroup%
      \lsthk@PreSet\gdef\lst@intname{#1}%
      \expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\lst@set}%
      \lsthk@DisplayStyle%
      \catcode\active=\active%
      \a:lstinputlisting\ht:special{t4ht@[}
      \pend:def\cptA:{\ht:special{t4ht@]}}
      \append:def\cptD:{\ht:special{t4ht@[}}
      \lst@Init\relax \let\lst@gobble\z@%
      \lst@SkipToFirst%
      \lst@ifprint \def\lst@next{\input{#1}}%
             \else \let\lst@next\@empty \fi%
      \ht:special{t4ht@]}\lst@next\ht:special{t4ht@[}\lst@DeInit\ht:special{t4ht@]}%
      \b:lstinputlisting%
    \endgroup}

\HLet\lst@InputListing\:tempa
\NewConfigure{lstinputlisting}{2}
\def\:tempa#1{%
   \setbox\z@\hbox{{\lst@currstyle{\kern#1}}}%
   \global\advance\lst@currlwidth \wd\z@
   \tmp:dim=#1 \let\:tempc=\empty
   \loop \ifdim \tmp:dim>\a:lst@Kern
      \advance \tmp:dim by -\a:lst@Kern
      \advance \tmp:dim by -\b:lst@Kern
      \append:def\:tempc{\:nbsp}%
   \repeat
   \setbox\z@\hbox{{\lst@currstyle{\:tempc}}}%
   \lst@OutputBox\z@}
\HLet\lst@Kern\:tempa
\NewConfigure{lst@Kern}{2}
\Configure{lst@Kern}{0.499em}{0.1em}
\def\lst@outputspace{\HCode{ }}

\HLet\lst@frameInit=\empty
\HLet\lst@frameExit=\empty

\Hinput{listings}
\endinput

With this change, there should be no errors. This is the result:

